# cache_sweeper function in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the purpose of this piece of code. I found it in audited-1.1.1 plugin under lib/act_as_audited/audit_sweeper.rb

```
class AuditSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper #:nodoc:
    def before_create(audit)
        audit.user ||= current_user
    end

    def current_user
        controller.send :current_user if controller.respond_to?(:current_user, true)
    end
end

 ActionController::Base.class_eval do
   extend CollectiveIdea::ActionController::Audited
   cache_sweeper :audit_sweeper
end
Audit.add_observer(AuditSweeper.instance)
```

What is cache_sweeper used for?

Answer (score 0):

The `cache_sweeper` are responsible for expiring cache when any object changes. Like if you have cached a user's and suppose you update the user's profile then the old cache should expire and new write should be performed. More details you can find on APIDock:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Caching/Sweeping

Edit:

This is like the `expires_in` in which we define time that it should expire in this much time. Here you can specify the action on which you need to expire like `edit, update, destroy`.